# Which membership plugin for a simple sign in? Personal areas for customers

Tags: plugins, login, membership, members, plugin-members

Most of the membership plugins I have found seemingly operate on the logic of the website having paying subscribers. I am not looking to make a publishing/blogging website with restricted access to articles. I am not interested in a plugin that I must continually pay for. I won't be billing my customers on a monthly basis.

Imagine a company website with a small login section.

I am looking for something that'll allow me to restrict access to certain areas, each individual area restricted to the specific customer. Within this area, they might have access to reports or statistics or links that are personal.

I need a plugin that'll assist me in maintaining a number of users, to which I myself have created their accounts (no sign-up procedure) and set the perimeters of access.

Is this doable with WordPress or should I be looking at an entirely different solution?

Comment: This is a tough question to answer because there are multiple methods to achieve what you're asking, so there is no 'accepted' solution.  That said, what would probably work best for you would be nothing more complex than restricting the content appearing on certain templates from users that do not have a minimum user role.  It's as easy as checking the level of the current user and determining if they can see the content on that page or not.  Add that to a template and assign that template to different pages that need to be hidden from the public.

Comment: I guess I'm in over my head with this one. I have decided to put the project on hold for now... maybe in a couple of months I'll have a better grasp of WordPress/other options. 

This functionality you describe, is that something that is allowed by WordPress all by itself, or do I need some plugin?

Comment: That’s default WP behavior.  Admin, Editor, Author, Contributor and Subscriber are already user roles built in.  Making a template for a theme is very standard practice as long as you’re using a custom theme or a child theme, so that you can edit / add to it.  If using a third party theme you’d have to put your template in a plugin which is slightly more complicated, but necessary as you shouldn’t be editing or adding to a third party theme, b/c your changes get deleted when it updates.

Comment: It may sound complex but I’d encourage you not to give up, I can help you with this.  It’s not as daunting as it sounds.

Comment: I guess my questions aren't "pro" enough, as I'm not even allowed to post them anymore. I will have to give up on this for now and move on to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with no subscription or payment features using the free [Restrict User Access](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-user-access/) plugin together with Wordpress User Roles (a bulit in feature).

You set the roles you want for each user, and each role defines access to particular set of content on your site.

The plugin's very flexible and granular, so it should do whatever you want. E.g. for restricting access to users it even goes down to making rules for the individual user

Comment: My current consideration is that of making a subdomain aside from the primary index.html for the login: login.site.com

To separate stuff.

Ever heard of [Member Hero](https://wordpress.org/plugins/member-hero/) ? I think it might be able to do something similar? 

Upon login, I want the user redirected to their own private area, where I'll set up a regular .html page with information that concerns them. Will Restrict User Access allow me to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds like at least one separate question which could be added as a new question to this stackexchange

Comment: I've been researching for 2 hours since my original question... Still haven't made up my mind, but hopefully I'll get to a point where I can intelligibly ask a question :)

I will research RUA and other options. Having all of these plugins makes it tough to navigate for a newcomer.